# HTML- Select path to root directory?

Tags: php, html

Working on my first website, and it's been going alright, except...

I'm using the same header (with dropdown menu) and footer on every page.  Since I will be dialing in the styling later, I set up an html file for each, and I'm using php includes to insert them into the pages so I can edit the header in just one place.

This worked great until I needed to create some pages in a subdirectory (to keep things organized).  Now I'm playing whack-a-mole with the header links. The pages linked to in the header are all in the public_html folder.  I thought by putting a / in front of the file name, it would work regardless of the location of the current page, but it does not.

I'm looking for a way to make a single link which can find public_html/index.php from both /public_html/page2.php and public_html/Subdirectory/page3.php.  I considered using absolute links, but I'm doing most of the editing on a localhost copy using XAMPP, then uploading to the server.  Besides, looks like everybody agrees that's bad form.

I've been searching for a clue, but I'm not sure I'm even framing the question properly.  Hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: What about relative links? `include "../header.php";`

Comment: A link to `/test.htm` will link to a file named `test.htm` placed in the root directory, no matter where your referring file is stored. `public_html` should not be visible in the URL. [This short article at CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) might be clarifying.

Comment: I'm assuming your `public_html` folder is the root directory of your webserver (this is the directory you reach when visiting your page from a web browser). In this case placing a / in front of the html links means they are absolute links and should always refer to the same place no matter which page they are included in. You may want to make sure that the folder name `public_html` isn't included in the links as this won't be visible publicly (e.g. to link to `public_html/index.php` your html should just refer to `/index.php`).

Comment: If your server configuration allows it, in your .htaccess file you can set the "paths" php should search by default. Keep your common files in, say, an _inc directory and then in your htaccess put: `php_value include_path '/path/to/_inc/:.'` Now the _inc directory is always searched first. (This value is also settable in php.ini if you have access to that, but with a different syntax.) It would also be good to find out what your default path is (`echo ini_get('include_path');`), and prepend that with your additional path.

Comment: To make the root directory the default relative point from which paths will be evaluated just set the include path to that instead: `php_value include_path '/path/to/public_html/:.'`

Answer (score 0):

**"Base" method**

The way I used to do it a while ago was to define the `__BASE__` in the root php file, so in your case it's `index.php` file I guess. It would look like this:

```
<?php 

    define('__BASE__', __DIR__);

    // other stuff and includes in index.php
```

then any file I included/required from `index.php` would have that costant available, so let's say you include `classes/anything.php`. Then in that file you can try to `echo` the `__BASE__` constant and see what you get.

```
<?php 

    echo __BASE__; // the absolute path to index.php (not always the root of your project)
```

If you have your `index.php` file somewhere else then the `root` of your project, I would recommend you to rewrite the `__BASE__` path to the root.

Let's say you have your `index.php` inside `/public_folder/` directory, then your `__BASE__` would be set to `__DIR__.'/../'` so it's pointing to your root dir.

This way you can access all of your files easily as the `__BASE__` is surly the root of your project and you can build the paths to all the files you need pretty easily.

To explain it a bit better, let's say you're structure is:

```
/ -> root of your project
/www/ -> root of the web server
/web-parts/ -> some of your files
```

Then in your `index.php`, which is inside the `/www/` directory you would define the `__BASE__`, as I did in the first example, with `/../` added to it (which would then point to your `/` [so-called "root"] directory).

After that, let's say your including some file from `/web-parts/` folder.

```
include(__BASE__.'web-parts/header.php'); // including some header.php file from /web-parts/ path
```

Of course, as you defined the `__BASE__` inside your `index.php` file which then included the `header.php` file, you're still able to use the `__BASE__` inside the `header.php`. So, for example, let's say you need to import `metas.html` file from the `/web-parts/someotherdirectory/` path into the `header.php` file.

```
<?php 
// header.php file
include(__BASE__.'web-parts/someotherdirectory/metas.html'); // you're still able to do this and you're still getting the absolute path
```

... and here you go. This way you keep things organized and you shouldn't have any problems when you'll be deploying your web-app.

**Composer**

I'm not sure about the level you're at right now, but if you do program you're web application using objects you can use composer's autoload for loading the classes. If you don't, you should definitely take a look at object-orientated programing, as it's pretty much needed right now.

I'm sorry if I understood the question poorly, but you can think about sharing your code samples if that doesn't help you.